# What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns?

Tags: single-word-requests, sentence-patterns, attributive-nouns

What word describes/denotes the words that precede *vision* in the following two words: **computer** vision and **machine** vision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word I hear most is *noun adjective*, while *attributive noun* and *noun adjunct* sound equally appropriate and current. I have never heard *noun premodifier*, though it sounds technically correct. I might prefer *adjectival noun* myself despite Wikipedia's reservations. A *noun adjective* is always a *modifier*, but not the other way around: *modifier* is a correct but less specific term.

[image]

While Ngrams are mere (defective) statistics and ultimately cannot support any such assertion, they may, when taken with a big lump of 'sea salt,' give readers some indication.

Comment: This certainly needs supporting evidence. I've never heard 'noun adjective', but I wouldn't post an answer giving the terms I am familiar with without supporting evidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't agree with you at all that evidence should be required, but, very well. See above.

Comment: But 'noun adjective' isn't defined as an 'attributive noun' in say [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun_adjective), but as a 'noun used in apposition.' Neither does [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012) list it as a synonym.

Answer (score 7):

I know it as an attributive noun, but according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_noun) Wikipedia article, it's also called a noun adjunct or noun premodifier.

Answer (score 2):

- Q1: What do you call it?

A noun preceding and describing other noun is called a *noun adjunct* or *attributive noun* or *noun premodifier*. 
Source [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198612508) calls it premodifier.

- Q2: Are they still nouns?

Yes, all the sources call them nouns.

- Q3: Are they adjectives?

From source [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/d26.html):

> Nouns used in this way are sometimes said to be adjectives or to behave like adjectives. **Attributive nouns** may be marked in dictionaries with a label like *often attrib* placed after the part-of-speech label for *noun*. While any noun may be used attributively, the label is limited to those quite frequently used in this manner. An adjective is defined as a word standing for the name of an attribute which describes a noun more fully, e.g., "yellow flower."

Source [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198612508) does not write that a noun can function as an adjective.

- Q4: How can a noun function as an adjective (what is the meaning of function)? Is this a rigorous definition?

More research needed

**Notes:**
-you can also have postmodifiers

-the premodifiers of nouns are usually adjectives, but they can also be nouns, genitive noun phrases, participles, adverbs, numerals, and others.

**Sources** I found and consulted:

- 1) [Oxford English Grammar, S.Greenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198612508)
- 2) Wikipedia's [Noun Adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) entry.
- 3) Dictionary.com [What is the difference between an attributive noun and an adjective?](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/d26.html)

Comment: The _source 3_ link takes to a completely different page, not the one from which the quote has been taken.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, *computer* in *computer vision* is a [modifier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/modifier), which is:

> A word, especially an adjective or noun used attributively, that restricts or adds to the sense of a head noun.

The same is true for *machine* in *machine vision*.

Examples of modifiers are:

- *Good* and *family* in *good family house*
- *London* in *London fog*