# Can "nuisance" be an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

According to Wiktionary there is a noun *[nuisance tax](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuisance_tax)*. Does this suggest *nuisance* can be an adjective? Is it?

Comment: There is an entry of nuisancey/nuisancy which means annoying, irritating in SOED (Shorter Oxford English Dictionary). However, I haven't found nor encountered anything close to nuisance used as an adjective. Most probably it's an adjectival noun (or often called compound noun).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is a [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

> In grammar, a *noun adjunct*, or *attributive noun*, or *noun premodifier* is a noun that modifies another noun, and is optional—meaning that it can be removed without changing the grammar of the sentence; it is a noun functioning as an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

*Nuisance* is not an adjective in the strictest sense.  *Nuisance tax* is what is known as a noun compound, and the first word in that phrase is known by a variety of names.  See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/what-is-the-word-that-denotes-the-words-preceding-these-nouns/) that talks about the variety of names (one is  *noun adjective*, interestingly).

Other common noun compound examples are *space shuttle* and *computer programming*.

Comment: The OED records 'nuisance' both as a noun and as an adjective.

Comment: Is there any way in which "nuisance" could be used as a predicate adjective?  Is there any context in which it could modify a noun other than by serving as a noun adjunct?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. Unfortunately, though this is a slightly unusual usage of "tax".

Normally, an *X tax* is a *tax on X*; *income tax* is a tax on your income, *sales tax* is a tax on the sale being made, *window tax* was a tax on the number of windows your house had, and so on.  In all of these cases, *X* is of necessity a noun.

I hadn't come across the term *nuisance tax* before and Etymonline doesn't list it, but the definition you link to suggests that it derives from the tax being a nuisance itself.  Despite the change in meaning, this is basically the same grammatical form as all the other taxes.

Answer (score 0):

I thought nuisant was the adjective form of nuisance.  ...a nuisant distraction (not all distractions have to be a nuisance).  But I can't seem to find an example of this, even though I thought I had heard it before and rather liked the adjective form.