# Can 'repeat' be an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

I was sure the word 'repeat' could be an adjective; for example, the phrase "repeat performance" describes a performance that is repeated.  To my surprise, however, the [Random House dictionary and World English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/repeat), don't have it in as an adjective, and nor does [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repeat).  So, is 'repeat' in "repeat performance" functioning as an adjective, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary also lists only the verb and the noun, but under the noun it has various *compounds*:

a.  Forming compounds denoting a further example or instance of the specified noun, as repeat business, repeat order, repeat performance, etc.

b.  Forming compounds denoting a person who does something (implied by the second element) again or repeatedly, as repeat customer, repeat offender, repeat viewer, repeat visitor, etc.

Linguists do not generally regard a modifier like "repeat" in "repeat performance" as an adjective, because it doesn't behave like an adjective in other ways (eg "*The performance was repeat", "*A very repeat performance", "*The repeatest performance")

Comment: Great answer.  Actually from [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/can-nuisance-be-an-adjective), it looks like "repeat performance" and the like are noun adjuncts.

Answer (score -1):

*Repeat* is a noun, but it is used also as an attribute to mean "occurring, done, or used more than once," as in "a repeat prescription."