# What do you call a noun that precedes and describes another noun?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/what-is-the-word-that-denotes-the-words-preceding-these-nouns)

Would it still be a noun, an adjective, or something else?

**Example:**

> A **stone** fortress

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I believe, the 'other things' are themselves going to be some kind of nouns, in that case:

> Nouns can sometimes describe other
>   nouns (such as a soccer ball). When
>   they do this, they are called
>   modifiers.

Quoted from and refer for more details: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun

Comment: Plus that Modifiers can be adjectives, adverbs, infinitive phrases and participle phrases.

Comment: Your answer is very ambiguous,I mean it has some mistakes.