# Identifying the class of this word

Tags: grammaticality, parts-of-speech

I'm reading the [Wikipedia page on garden-path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence). One example is:

> The government plans to raise taxes were defeated.

What class of word is *government* in this sentence?

I read this sentence as having the subject noun "plans". "Government" describes the noun, which would make it an adjective. I thought that the adjective form of "government" was "governmental".

The sentence may imply ownership of the plans by the government (as opposed to describing the *type* of plans, distinct from council plans or building plans). In this case, I would have written it as "the government's plans...".

Either way, I'm unsure how to determine whether the given sentence is grammatically correct. Assuming it is, what class of word is *government*?

[Slightly separate question: what's the correct term for "the class of word", such as 'adjective', 'noun'? Had issues phrasing my question without knowing this.]

Comment: The ***part of speech*** (or ***lexical class***) of *government* is an *attributive noun*. See [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113965/correct-form-of-genitive-case) and [this one on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/churchs-tradition-or-church-tradition), also linked there.

Comment: Informally, the word 'government' is modifying the object 'plans'...what kind of plans are they? They are plans made by the government. The label of part of speech is contentious. Is it a noun or is it an adjective? Well, it is usually called some kind of noun that acts like an adjective (e.g. Andrews 'attributive noun'.

Comment: Interestingly, until quite recently **attributive noun** meant 'adjective'. The Classical Eight Parts of Speech (_Partes Orationis_) included Noun but not Adjective ("Participle" made up the difference, but it has slipped from the approved list recently), because adjectives behaved just like nouns as far as the Romans were concerned -- same endings, same uses, etc. To the extent they distinguished between them, they called them _Nomen Adjectivum_, a translation of Greek _onoma epitheton_ 'attributive name'.

Comment: Now the canon requires that there be a difference between the Noun and the Adjective, and we find ourselves once more saddled with terminology like "attributive noun" to refer to Official nouns who are behaving like they were Official adjectives, and confusing students once again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/what-is-the-word-that-denotes-the-words-preceding-these-nouns/15716#15716) Note that noun adjectives appear to be used more now than in the past; excessive use of noun adjectives is generally advised against by style books. As to your example, I agree with Bill.

Answer (score 2):

The word *government* in the example sentence is a noun that functions as an adjective. It's typical native-speaker usage. The reason that it's a garden-path sentence is that at first glance, the reader will most likely think that the subject of the sentence is *government* and that the main verb of the sentence is *plans*.

The sentence is grammatical, but it's awkward because it initially confuses the reader, who has to stop and reread to parse the sentence. This is a mark of poor style.

To avoid the the garden path, the sentence should be changed to read:

> The **government's** plans to raise taxes were defeated.
>
> *Governmental plans* to raise taxes were defeated.

isn't a really good option despite its grammaticality. It sounds bad to me and will probably not be appealing to most native Anglophones.

The rule about part of speech (POS) is that words don't change POS, but some words are classified as both adverbs and adjectives, for example, as is the case with *loud* and *fast*.

More important than what POS a word is, is how the word functions in a particular context. *What does it do?* is a more important question than *What part of speech is it?*

Comment: Great critique although I think the OP knows about garden-pathology. But there's no answer to the question here.

Comment: @Andrew: I like that "garden-pathology" coinage. :-) A sense of humor is a good thing to have.